# How to access second iCollection from model and iterate over that collection to get their datatypes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

Is there a way, in my view, which has as its model Exer_Workout, to access the deep nested ICollection of: Exer_Set_Pivot, and Get the data types of its members in a foreach loop? 
First Model Class:

```
public partial class Exer_Workout
{
    public Exer_Workout()
    {
        this.Exer_Routine = new HashSet<Exer_Routine>();
    }

    public int ObjID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Exer_Routine> Exer_Routine { get; set; }
}
```

Second Model (one to many from 1st model):

```
public partial class Exer_Routine
{
    public Exer_Routine()
    {
        this.Exer_Set_Pivot = new HashSet<Exer_Set_Pivot>();
    }

    public int ObjID { get; set; }
    public int WorkoutID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Exer_Workout Exer_Workout { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exer_Set_Pivot> Exer_Set_Pivot { get; set; }
}
```

My third Model Class which has a one to many with my second model class:

```
public Exer_Set_Pivot()
    {
        this.Exer_Set = new HashSet<Exer_Set>();
    }

    public int ObjID { get; set; }
    public int RoutineID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Weight { get; set; }
    public bool WeightUnit { get; set; }
    public bool Reps { get; set; }
    public bool Challenge { get; set; }
    public bool ElapsedTime { get; set; }
    public bool Distance { get; set; }
    public bool DistanceUnit { get; set; }
    public bool Speed { get; set; }
    public bool SpeedUnit { get; set; }

    public virtual Exer_Routine Exer_Routine { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exer_Set> Exer_Set { get; set; }
}
```

My partial view which needs to access the Exer_Set_Pivot members and determine their date types, and if they are of type(bool) set them into checkboxes:

```
@model Diabuddies.Models.Exer_Workout


<fieldset>
<legend>Set @ViewBag.SC   </legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Exer_RoutineList[Model.RoutineCount].Exer_SetPivotList[Model.SetCount].Name)
            @* <input type="text" name="Workout.Exer_Routine[@ViewBag.RC].Exer_Set_Pivot[@ViewBag.SC].Name"> *@ 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Description:
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Exer_RoutineList[Model.RoutineCount].Exer_SetPivotList[Model.SetCount].Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Repeat Set:</td>
        <td>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Exer_RoutineList[Model.RoutineCount].Exer_SetPivotList[Model.SetCount].RepeatSet, new { maxlength=3 }) 
        </td>
    </tr>
    >>>>>HERE<<<<< DSFSADLFSDLFK DSL FKDSLFKLDSKF
    @foreach (dfgdfgdfg)
    {

        @*This is where I am stuck.  Need to get Exer_Set_Pivot's members and determine their type *@

           <tr>
           <td>
               System.Collections.Generic.List
           </td>
           <td>
               @(listitem.GetType()) and put it into checkbox, just need to get here.
           </td> 
           </tr> 

    }   
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve all this with reflection but it would lead to a really horrible code. You'd better access individual members of the view model:

```
@foreach (Exer_Routine routine in Model.Exer_Routine)
{
    <tr>
    @foreach (Exer_Set_Pivot pivot in routine.Exer_Set_Pivot)
    {
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Weight)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.WeightUnit)
        </td>
        ...
    }
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Exer_Routine is not accessible like this.  Also I only create checkboxes if type is bool.

Comment: What do you mean it's not accessible? Your view model is `Exer_Workout` which has a property called `Exer_Routine`, so it's exactly with `Model.Exer_Routine` that you would access this collection property.

Comment: var routine in Exer_Routine works - my bad, and thank you.  But now that I can drill down to Exer_Set_Pivot, how do I iterate through that model and if a system.type == bool, catch?